# BackBone.js CORS Connection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, cors

I have tried a lot to connect to some other domain using backbone.js.

But couldn't be able to perform.

I tried to override sync method, even tried ajax call in backbone.js, tried java script also. but couldn't succeed.

I don't know how to proceed further. any help will be appreciable..

Answer (score 0):

Seems like CORS problem, you could not sove this with client side only.

To test API CORS support you can use test CORS

So you can solve this by:

Implement CORS support on API server side.
Proxy requests from your app server side to API.
Use another techies to cross-origin policy like(JSONP, etc..)